# differential equation, general form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's such a crazy question, but I just confused that how can I find general solution!!? $$
2y''-y'=1, \qquad y(0)=0, \qquad y'(0)=0 $$
I tried with these forms but couldn't find!

- 1) $y=c_1c^x + c_2xe^x$
- 2) $y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x+a_3x^2+...$

Comment: You could just integrate once to $2y'-y=x$. Can you explain how you came to these specific trial solutions?

Comment: I just read about these general forms on the internet

Comment: While not everything you read on the internet is fake, it is unlikely that it will be universally applicable. Surely there were conditions that tell when you can apply these forms, and what the general method is.

Comment: $$y=C_1e^{x/2}+C_2-x$$ works.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& 2y''-y'=1 \\
\implies & (2y'-y)'=1 \\
\implies & 2y'-y=x+A \\
\end{align}

At this point, use your initial conditions to see that $A=0$. So we have

\begin{align}
& 2y'-y=x \\
\implies & e^{-x/2}y'-\frac 12 ye^{-x/2} = \frac 12 x e^{-x/2} \\
\implies & \big(e^{-x/2}y\big)' = \frac 12 x e^{-x/2} \\
\implies & e^{-x/2}y = -(x+2)e^{-x/2}+B
\end{align}

Use initial conditions again to see that $B=2$. Therefore,

$$y(x) = 2e^{x/2}-x-2$$

---

The step of multiplying through by $e^{-x/2}$ is called using an "integrating factor". So going back to when we had

$$2y'-y=x$$

You first have to make sure that the coefficient of $y'$ is $1$, so divide by $2$ to get

$$y'-\frac 12 y = \frac 12 x$$

Now note that the method of integrating factors only works when your equation is in the form

$$y'+F(x)y = G(x)$$

where it is important to note that $F,G$ are functions of ONLY $x$. The integrating factor is computed by

$$\exp{\bigg(\int F(x)dx \bigg)}$$

In this case, we have $F(x) = -\frac 12$, hence the integrating factor is

$$\exp{\bigg(\int -\frac 12 dx \bigg)} = e^{-x/2}$$

Comment: Could you please let me know how you found $$e^{−x/2}$$ and multiplied both side with this?

Comment: It is a standard technique. @mohammad2232

Comment: Here, I edited my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: @glowstonetrees thank you, could you please also let me know reference(An English book) for this?